# Is the comma appropriate in "...for a few years, expecially in those parts"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> People's interest in their ancestors' background has been increasing for few years, especially in those parts of the world where the majority of the population has immigrants from different parts of the planet.

Before the start of a phrase (especially....), I inserted a comma to avoid confusion. Can I use it to avoid confusion?.

Comment: What is the origin of this sentence? What source does it come from?

Comment: This comma is not only allowed, it's highly desirable.

Comment: "the majority of the population has immigrants" doesn't make sense, I think you mean " the majority of the population are immigrants" in which case "from different parts of the planet." is unnecessary repetition.

Comment: @LukeSawczak, will the comma usage be acceptable for an examiner.

Comment: @RaheelBari An examiner will expect that comma, yes.

Comment: You do need to be careful that you really mean "*few* years" and not "*a few* years".  Like "little"/"a little", the first means a much smaller number than the second.

Comment: Yes, it's completely acceptable to use a comma there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the comma is appropriate because you are using a  *parenthetical phrase*.

You may have been taught that commas can be used instead of parentheses (brackets), for example:

> All children (except mine) seem to like ice cream.

This could also be written as:

> All children, except mine, seem to like ice cream.

You could actually write your sentence as:

> People's interest in their ancestors' background *(especially in those parts of the world where the majority of the population has immigrants from different parts of the planet)* has been increasing for a few years.

Your sentence structure actually makes more sense and is more readable, but you can see from this alternative rendering why the second part of your sentence is a separate clause. The single comma separates the main statement from the parenthetical phrase.

Just one last thing - your sentence was missing an "a" - compare with my example above.

Comment: I'd also recommend "parts of the world where the majority of the population **is made up of** immigrants from different parts of the planet". It is not possible for the "majority of the population" to *have immigrants*. The majority *are* immigrants.